# (one line if) ? bool is true - give me string

Tags: c#, .net

I can't wrap by head around this even though I've read many stackoverflow threads.

I check if the page has a specific property value like so:

```
bool categoryCount = CurrentPage.HasValue("blogCategories");
```

I want to transform this into a one-line if statement so I can parse a string to a class like illustrated below:

```
string situation = (categoryCount.ToString() == "true") ? '' : '';
```

PS: I apologize for the missing logic behind my thoughts/goal. I'm new at programming.

Comment: Why are you converting the bool to a string?  Why do you need this condition anyway if both results return the same value?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: No need to convert a bool to a string.

Comment: If there is any categories I want to add a class to a grid. So if there is a category I want to add `<div class="grid-2">` if there isn't a class I want to add `<div class="grid-12">`. By the way, I'm new at programming so I apologize for the missing logic behind my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
string situation = (CurrentPage.HasValue("blogCategories"))
                   ? "Has the value" : "Has NOT that value";
```

You should change two things:

1. do **not work with `ToString() == "True"`**, simply put the boolean (expression) in the condition part of the *ternary operator*: it is inefficient to call `ToString()` and furthermore if the specifications change, it might stop working (actually `true.ToString()` returns `"True"`, with a capital, so it will not work with your code);
2. use **string literals** `"some string"`, not char literals `'a'`: the result is supposed to be a `string`, not a `char`.

By comparing with `"true"`, this will not work:

```
csharp> true.ToString()   
"True"                    
csharp> true.ToString() == "true" 
false
```

But even if it would work, it would be rather unsafe: if later the designers of the .NET library change their minds, then your program could stop working correctly. Usually I think it is better *not* to rely on the format of a `ToString()` method. These tend to be culture specific, and furthermore usually do not offer hard constraints with respect to the output format anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert to string to use ternary. You can simply just do this:

```
string situation = categoryCount ? "Executes if true" : "Executes if false";
```

The ternary condition doesn't need to be a string, just the returns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert a bool to a string to find out if it's `true`.

Do you know what this returns if `categoryCount` has the boolean value `true`?

```
bool x = categoryCount.ToString() == "true";
```

It returns the boolean value `true`. If `categoryCount` is `true`, then it *is true* that its string representation is equal to "true". But `categoryCount` is `true` already.

It is exactly the same as this:

```
bool x = categoryCount;
```

Also, a string in C# uses double quotes, not single quotes.

So:

```
string situation = categoryCount ? "one string" : "another string";
```